# Using Multiple Regex Patterns in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a little example here of creating a PySpark DataFrame which contains the names of some James Bond films. I am using three different regex patterns to find the films I am interested in.

```
columns = ["BondFilms", "FilmId"]

films = [
  ("Dr. No",101),
  ("From Russia with Love", 102),
  ("Goldfinger", 103),
  ("Thunderball", 104),
  ("You Only Live Twice", 105),
  ("On Her Majesty's Secret Service", 106),
  ("Diamonds Are Forever", 107),
  ("Live and Let Die", 108),
  ("The Man with the Golden Gun", 109),
  ("The Spy Who Loved Me", 110),
  ("Moonraker", 111),
  ("For Your Eyes Only", 112),
  ("Octopussy", 113),
  ("A View to a Kill", 114),
  ("The Living Daylights", 115),
  ("Licence to Kill", 116),
  ("GoldenEye", 117),
  ("Tomorrow Never Dies", 118),
  ("The World Is Not Enough", 119),
  ("Die Another Day", 120),
  ("Casino Royale", 121),
  ("Quantum of Solace", 122),
  ("Skyfall", 123),
  ("Spectre", 124),
  ("No Time to Die", 125),
  ("Total of Eon-produced films", 126)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=films, schema=columns)

p1 = "^The "
p2 = "^You "
p3 = "^From"

df = df.filter(df['BondFilms'].rlike("|".join([p1, p2, p3])))

df.display()
```

While there are only 3 patterns in this example, it looks and feels pretty clean.

However if I had a much larger dataset with hundreds of patterns, adding them all into the "join" feel a bit dirty. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you going to have hundreds of patterns, then no matter how “clean” your code is, it’s still messy, because that’s hoa regular expression patterns work. The best approach is maybe rethinking about your solution on how to filter the titles you want, like adding extra columns, or some sort of ranking or labeling…